# What's the German for "A Bird in Hand..."?

Tags: proverb

I remember the proverb as something like, "Ein Spass in der Hand (versus) Ein Vögel, am Dach."

Or something like a sparrow in hand versus a bird on the roof.

The best support I could find was [this link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TVXqG80auxw) about something on the head (versus) a Spass.

I'm using a "mapping algorithm" that says that a roof may serve a similar function to a head (in being on top).

So I'm a bit confused about something in hand being compared to something on "top," as opposed to in the bush.

And a LOT more confused about the one-to-one relationship between a sparrow in hand, and the bird, or whatever, wherever.

Comment: If you like Heinz Erhardt, the correct version is "Lieber 'ne Stumme im Bett als eine Taube auf dem Dach."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"Ein Spatz in der Hand ist besser als eine Taube auf dem Dach."

It means a small thing you have for sure is better than hoping for a big thing you might get (but probably won't).

"Spatz" is a sparrow, a smaller bird than a dove ("Taube").

Comment: A dove is a small bird also. But I remember Taube as being a different, perhaps larger bird.

Comment: It seems doves are very variable in size. Here in Germany the standard ones are substantially bigger than a sparrow, the bigger ones are the size of small chickens ("Ringeltaube").

Comment: Here, doves are much bigger than sparrows, not comparable really.

Comment: Maybe the proverb is not about size but about beauty.

Comment: Pigeons/doves can also be eaten - and they were served as food in the times this saying originates.

Comment: @Takkat: But were sparrows also served as food?

Comment: @Stefan Walter: I was not alive then but I guess so - in Italy some people (illegally) serve singbirds as a delicacy...

Comment: OK, it's a PIGEON (rather than a dove) that is much larger than a sparrow. And while English compares one bird to TWO birds, German compares a SMALL bird to a BIG(ger) bird.

Comment: @Takkat Pigeons are even eaten here today, the surplus ones from breeding them.

Comment: @TomAu from english wikipedia: *The distinction between "doves" and "pigeons" in English is not consistent, and does not exist in most other languages. In everyday speech, "dove" frequently indicates a pigeon that is white or nearly white; some people use the terms "dove" and "pigeon" interchangeably. In contrast, in scientific and ornithological practice, "dove" tends to be used for smaller species and "pigeon" for larger ones, but this is in no way consistently applied.*